# Redirect http:// to all pages https://

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl

I'd like to redirect all pages from http:// to https://.

I'm using the Kohana framework but only the homepage redirects.  I go to `example.com/anyoldpage`, but it doesn't even redirect to http:// if I go to `http://example.com/anyoldpages`, but if I go to `https://example.com`, it works.

Can anyone please help me?   The `rel="canonical"` works across the website.
For example:
If user lands on `http://example.com/anyoldpage` or `http://www.example.com/anyoldpage` any page the `rel="canonical"` works and presents https:// so in SEO terms it works great. However I'm going to be buying the green bar SSL certificate so really want this .htaccess file to work.

The current code is.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^do-main  com [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Please help and thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you have some extra lines, so just do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Hey I tried that, but it still isn't redirecting to https

Comment: I was able to find this.


RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]